# Is it possible to change the analyzer specified in the schema in Solr without reindexing from the original source?

Tags: solr, indexing, schema-design

In Solr, if we have a field in the schema with stored="true", and we change the analyzer associated with that field, is it possible to update just this field without reindexing all the documents? Could this be done using the "stored" values of the field with the new analyzer without going back to the original data source?

Comment: This seems similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105542/customizing-analyzers-in-solr/9107815#comment11455477_9107815) .

Answer (score 1):

Guy, I optimized your code.

```
    ...
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        ...
        //server.deleteById(id) ;
        //server.commit() ;

        Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
        docs.add(inputdoc) ;
        server.add(docs) ;
        // server.commit() ;
    }
    server.commit() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using SolrJ.

```
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();

        query.setQuery( "whatever_by_id" );

        QueryResponse rsp;

        rsp = server.query(query);

        Iterator<SolrDocument> iter = rsp.getResults().iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            SolrDocument resultDoc = iter.next();
            String id = (String) resultDoc.getFieldValue("oid"); //id is the uniqueKey field

            SolrInputDocument inputdoc = new SolrInputDocument() ;
            for( Map.Entry<String, Object> f : resultDoc.entrySet()) {
                inputdoc.setField(f.getKey(), f.getValue()) ;
            }

            server.deleteById(id) ;
            server.commit() ;

            Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
            docs.add(inputdoc) ;
            server.add(docs) ;

            server.commit() ;
        }
```

When we add the "new" inputdoc (a copy of the old resultDoc), it uses the new analyzer we have changed in the schema to index. It´s not very elegant, but it works.

Comment: Yes xD, but not all the documents. First full-import took 8 hours and I do not want to repeat it xD.

Answer (score 0):

check out this [IBM Tutorial for Solr](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-solr1/)