# change schema from indexed field to stored field without re-index in Solr

Tags: solr

We want to change schema from indexed field to stored field, for example

orig one : `<field name="cat" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false">`

new one: `<field name="cat" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true">`

The tool or commands to help to achieve this without re-index all the documents?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating Solr Schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038920/updating-solr-schema)

Answer (score 1):

If you change your schema you have to re-index your documents.  You could use multiple cores to avoid a restart of the servlet container, see Core RELOAD but you do need to re-index.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. When field is not stored, you have no option to fetch content for this field from index.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... you really can't do that, you must have to re-index.

But re-index cannot be a problem, if you have a lot of docs you can use one of the SOLR imports or if you have a slave solr that is replicating with a master, you can stop the replication, re-index in master, and start the replication again.

re-index is boring right? ^^