# Can I change Schema.xml file structure after starting the index in solr?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have configured solr and right now I am using two filed in Schema.xml:

- file_id
- content

After I start the indexing I have already index around 1000 of records now I want to
add more fields in Schema.xml.

Is it possible to update current Schema.xml file without effecting the indexing data?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038920/updating-solr-schema http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037625/change-schema-in-solr-without-reindex

Answer (score 2):

In every case you have to restart the solr/lucene instance. If you add new fields into the schema.xml (which mean: lucene will provide more/new informations) you have to refresh/rebuild the index.