# Customizing Analyzers in Solr

Tags: solr, analyzer

In Solr I have a custom Analyzer that has two parameters. I know how to specify this Analyzer in the schema.xml but I'm wondering how I can pass the two arguments either in the schema.xml or runtime in the code.

Comment: Did you refer to Solr Wiki, [Custom Analyzer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#Analyzer). <filter class="my.package.CustomTokenFilter" optA="yes" optB="maybe"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not pass parameters to the schema xml at run-time , as far as I know. 
But you can use the reload command.This can be useful when (backwards compatible) changes have been made to your solrconfig.xml or schema.xml files (e.g. new  declarations, changed default params for a , etc...) and you want to start using them without stopping and restarting your whole Servlet Container.

see [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD)

Comment: Seems a bit drastic to reload the schema just to change a config argument.But I'll accept your answer, thanks!